# Как правильно проектировать классы с большим количеством обязательных параметров?

Tags: c#, классы, проектирование

Мне требуется создать достаточно массивный класс, координирующий работу ряда объектов. Для его работы необходимо отправить ему около пятнадцати объектов. Без них его работа не возможна, по этому было принято решение отправлять все объекты через конструктор. Естественно, что конструктор на 10+ аргументов выглядит просто ужасно! Есть альтернатива отправлять все объекты посредством свойств, но этот способ имеет свои недостатки. Придётся лепить дополнительные проверки на null и выкидывать исключения. Да и стороннему разработчику, если потребуется работать с таким классом придётся потратить дополнительный усилия, что бы не пропустить никакого важного свойства.

Как быть? Множество аргументов в конструкторе? Или множество свойств обязательных к заполнению?

Comment: Интересно, как ваш класс координирует работу классов, если класс - это что-то вроде чертежа. Ну да ладно. Покажите пример кода, что ужасного в большом конструкторе? И в чём проблема свойств? Их можно заполнять значениями по умолчанию в конструкторе без аргументов, а потом инициализировать нужные.

Comment: а не разделить ли класс раз так много параметров принимает?

Comment: "Интересно, как ваш класс координирует работу классов" тут очепятался чуть чуть, я имел ввиду экземпляры.
"а не разделить ли класс раз так много параметров принимает?"
Разделить, конечно, можно, но, по-моему, это будет не правильно.

Comment: Пример кода был бы явно не лишний.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Есть такой анти-паттерн **God** он же **Божественный объект**. Его главная особенность — он может всё. Такой объект нарушает принцип *единственной ответственности*, и, скорее всего, его можно разбить на три или четыре несвязанных класса.

Если посмотреть на ту же ситуацию под другим углом зрения, можно говорить о ней, как об ошибке декомпозиции: перескакивании на несколько уровней вниз. Например, вещество состоит из молекул, молекулы из атомов, атомы из протонов, нейтронов и электронов, протоны и электроны — из кварков. Естественно, можно сказать, что молекулы состоят из протонов и электронов, и это правда, но, пропустив атомы, вы получаете весьма запутанную картину молекулы. Атомы позволяют значительно упростить модель.

Боб Мартин в книге *Чистый код* описывает один из запахов кода: вызов методов разного уровня детализации. Этот тот случай, когда декомпозируя молекулы, программист иногда работает с ними как с набором атомов, а иногда, как с набором элементарных частиц.

Скорее всего в данном случае можно отказаться от пятнадцати классов, в пользу трёх-четырёх, каждый из которых состоит из трёх-четырёх более мелких классов.

Количество классов у вас увеличится, поскольку появятся промежуточные; зато каждый из них теперь будет простым для понимания.

С другой стороны, бывают ситуации, когда большое количество параметров вполне допустимо. Мартин Фаулер описал паттерн **Registry** (**Реестр**), который предоставляет доступ к набору однотипных объектов. Скажем, вам нужно 5 или 6 репозиториев и, вместо того, чтобы передавать их по одному, вы заводите реестр репозиториев и передаёте только один этот объект. При этом у самого реестра в качестве параметров конструктора теперь передаются все репозитории, которые есть в вашей программе. Поскольку все репозитории относятся к одной *категории* объектов, код реестра получается простым и понятным. При этом конструктор реестра имеет 15-20 параметров и это всё равно выглядят ужасно. Я бы назвал этот случай неизбежным злом, и отнёс бы его причину к ограниченным выразительным средствам языка. В общем, иногда мы просто вынуждены писать так, потому что по другому язык не позволяет. Но будьте осторожны — прежде чем решить, что всё с вашим кодом в порядке, проверьте, что речь не идёт о первом случае: божественном объекте и смешении уровней детализации.

Comment: Все круто, но откуда цифры что скорей всего можно разделить именно на три или четыре класса? А не на семь например.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Моё личное мнение, которое, скорее всего, трудно будет документально подтвердить — что именно в этом и заключается мастерство программиста: спроектировать понятно. Подспорьем является, то, что мы говорим о модели, а не о реальности. В реальности любая программа состоит из примитивных команд процессора, а классы, паттерны и сообщения — это условности, помогающие программистам писать и понимать большие программы. Поэтому 14-15-16 примитивов можно объединить в 1 класс по 15, в 7 по 2 и в 4 по 4. Последний вариант лично мне кажется самым понятным.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите сократить запись при создании экземпляров вашего управляющего класса, то вам в первую очередь следует задуматься о значениях по умолчанию. Например, у вас есть нужные вам свойства, которые вы в конструкторе без аргументов инициализируете корректными значениями, как-то так:

```
public class SomeManager
{
    public object   Property01 {get; set; }
    public object   Property02 {get; set; }
    public int      Property03 {get; set; }
    public double   Property04 {get; set; }
    public string   Property05 {get; set; }
    public int      Property06 {get; set; }
    public DateTime Property07 {get; set; }
    public object   Property08 {get; set; }
    public object   Property09 {get; set; }
    public object   Property10 {get; set; }
    public object   Property11 {get; set; }

    public SomeManager()
    {
        Property01 = null;
        Property02 = null;
        Property03 = 100;
        Property04 = 0.33;
        Property05 = "Здесь был Вася";
        Property06 = 8;
        Property07 = DateTime.UtcNow;
        Property08 = null;
        Property09 = null;
        Property10 = null;
        Property11 = null;
    }
}
```

Соответственно, при работе с экземплярами этого класса, вы сможете создавать их в нужной конфигурации, не расписывая портянку в пол-экрана. Вот так:

```
var man1 = new SomeManager()
{
    Property01 = SomeList,
    Property05 = "Никаких Вась здесь не было"
}
```

Или так:

```
var man2 = new SomeManager()
{
    Property03 = 42,
    Property04 = 0.5,
    Property07 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
}
```

Так же можно перегрузить конструктор столько раз, сколько вам надо, но если вариантов много - решение так себе.

---

С другой стороны - в большинстве случаев использования классов-менеджеров желательно избегать (**upd** - я имею в виду God-объекты из другого ответа). Может быть, вам пересмотреть архитектуру?

Comment: "С другой стороны - в большинстве случаев использования классов-менеджеров желательно избегать." — почему?

Comment: @BlackWitcher пока писал, появился второй ответ, в котором ответили гораздо лучше меня

Comment: А, спасибо, понятно теперь, что вы имели ввиду. Я-то удивился потому как совершенно спокойно отношусь к классам типа всяких Print - Report и прочих менеджеров, которые решают одну (и только одну) возложенную на них задачу не нарушая принципов SOLID. Вот и здесь подумал, что как раз речь идет о каком-то менеджере реестров или сходных объектов, который можно превратить в фабрику, например. Ответили [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/591528/222168) совершенно верно про **God**, и изначально вопрос поставлен весьма обще, потому и попросил у автора вопроса пример кода. :-)

Comment: Ну, я, исходя из вопроса, понял, что у автора менеджер очень разных объектов, потому что он пишет про обработку нулей и исключений. То есть, видимо, у каких-то объектов каких-то свойств/полей нет

Comment: Ага, здесь можно лишь предполагать, но изначально это могут быть и сходные по какому-то одному признаку объекты, но с различиями по иным признакам. Банальный пример - транспорт, но он тоже бывает разный, водный, воздушный, наземный... Каждый из которых тоже может быть разделен на подкатегории, например, наземный - ж/д и авто. Ну и т.д. Соответственно, получается, что вроде и общность есть, но есть и разница (оттого и проверки на null).
В общем, это я к тому, что пока автор вопроса не даст более конкретную информацию и/или код, сложно ответить более конкретно, нежели чем уже отвечено )